# comparing object calling the method

Tags: java, methods, boolean

i know this is very trivial, but for some reason i'm having a little trouble. i'm trying to write a method that has a book object from an array list calling the method that compares it to another book in the same list. I think i got the gist of it but i'm just not understanding how to compare them. i think it's supposed to look something like this.

```
 public Boolean isShorter(Book otherBook)
 { 
    if(otherBook.getLength() < ???????.getLength() )
          return true;
    else  
          return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have a book internally from the class? `this.getLength()`?

Comment: As an aside, return `boolean` rather than `Boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

use "this" keyword to refer to the current object (the caller of the method).
like this:

```
otherBook.getLength() < this.getLength()
```

Comment: thanks you. Using "this" has kinda confused me on when to use it, but I think i'm starting to understand it better. much appreciated.